# Assigning smaller number of values to larger number of values in R

Tags: r

I have two large vectors:

```
A: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/A.csv
B: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/B.csv
```

A has over 20000 entries but only 1350 unique entries.
B is a random number generated from 1 to 9 exactly 1350 times

I would like to assign values from B to A such that the same values in A get the same values in B. e.g. if there are multiple 1's each 1 should get the same number from B.

I have been using the A[B] command but after the 18000th entry I get NAs

What is the proper way of doing this?

code:

```
A<-read.csv("A.csv")
B<-read.csv("B.csv")

A[B]
```

Comment: Have you tried to `merge()`?

Comment: merge won't assign the same values the same number. E.g. if there are four 1s each of those four should get the same number from B

Comment: `merge()` will do that, if you explore the `all.x=TRUE` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `read.csv()` creates a data frame, not a vector.
2. You probably mean `B[A]` which for each element in A gets the value of B at the index of that element's value. Since A's values range from 1 to 1899 it exceeds B's size of 1349. For those elements outside the bounds of B, NAs get introduced.

The correct way to doing what you want to achieve is

```
A = read.table("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/A.csv")
B = read.table("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/B.csv")
A = A$V1
B = B$V1
A = as.factor(A)

B[match(A,levels(A))]
```

`match(A,levels(A))` will return a vector of the same length as A that for each element contains the position of the element of A in its factor's levels, i.e. a number between 1 and 1350 (1350 distinct values). If A was `as.factor(c(1,1,3,5,5,7))`, `levels(A)` would be `c(1,3,5,7)` and `match(A,levels(A))` would be `c(1,1,2,3,3,4)`, i.e. the position of the element in it's levels.

Comment: why do I have to make it 1350? I don't understand.

Comment: My mistake. From your question I assumed that those files were in CSV format but they are not. I modified my answer.